# Can't find error in php, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'preg_match' (T_STRING)

Tags: php

New to php. I'm having trouble determining the error in my code. I keep getting this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'preg_match' (T_STRING) in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blackiris/blackiris/syriaexhibition/syriaexhibition.php
>   on line 16

```
header('content-type: text/plain');
$contents = file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_sort=video_date_uploaded&search_query=syria');
$contents = preg_replace('/\s(1,)/', ' ', $contents);

print $contents . "\n";
// if ($contents === false)
//  print 'False';
// print_r($contents);
$records = $preg_split('/<h3 class="yt/', $contents);

for ($ix = 1; $ix < count($records); $ix++)  (
$tmp = $records[$ix]

preg_match('/href="(.*?)"/', $tmp, $match_url);

print_r($match_url);

exit();
)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them

Answer (score 1):

You need a semicolon after `$tmp = $records[$ix]` and the `(` and `)` in the foreach should be `{` and `}`:

```
for ($ix = 1; $ix < count($records); $ix++)  {
  $tmp = $records[$ix];                   // ^ //
                   // ^ //
  preg_match('/href="(.*?)"/', $tmp, $match_url));

  print_r($match_url);

  exit();
}  // < //
```